# Notify when a user is dropped in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to figure out something where, if someone drops the user in mysql, I need to send email. Is there any way to accomplish this? 
Definitely I cannot add trigger on mysql.user table. 
Thinking of creating a table which is replica to mysql.user in some other database(lets say foo), and polling this table and seeing whether there is any change when compared to mysql.user.If yes, then send email, update the replica(foo.user) table accordingly. IS there any other way to do this?

Comment: how is a user dropped in the first place?

Comment: @DanielHunter using the syntax DROP USER user;..

Comment: when you query DROP USER send a mail then?

Comment: @nischayn22 when ever someone drops the user, it need not be instantaneous, but should be notified ASAP

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling the db in PHP then:

1. trigger the drop user event
2. check for success
3. trigger email event

no need to clone your db

Comment: do you mean something like web interface for database? Unfortunately I don't have that option.